# Pandas - count frequencies in bin intervals

Tags: pandas

I have a time series of measured data stored in pandas dataframe: wind speeds VEL and wind directions DIR. Each record is measured every hour HH (and should weigh the same). YYYY MM DD is the date.

```
YYYY MM DD HH DIR VEL
1990 1 1 1 112.0 4.1
1990 1 1 2 121.0 3.6
1990 1 1 3 27.0 3.1
1990 1 1 4 48.0 2.1
1990 1 1 5 129.0 2.6
1990 1 1 6 61.0 1.1
1990 1 1 7 78.0 3.1
1990 1 1 8 12.0 1.6
1990 1 1 9 37.0 2.6
```

I want to specify intervals for wind speeds (header 'VEL') and wind directions ('DIR'). Then, I want to create a new dataframe that counts the frequency in those intervals.

```
dir_interval = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
vel_interval = [0,60,120,180,240,300,360]

           0-1   1-2  2-3 3-4  4-5  
0 - 60            2    1          
60 - 120    1     1    1   1    1    
120 - 180              1   1         
180 - 240                         
240 - 300                            
300 - 360
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to mess up `dir_interval` and `vel_interval`. That said, I think you are looking for `crosstab` along with `cut`:

```
pd.crosstab(pd.cut(df['DIR'], vel_interval),
           pd.cut(df['VEL'], dir_interval))
```

Output:

```
VEL         (1, 2]  (2, 3]  (3, 4]  (4, 5]
DIR                                       
(0, 60]          1       2       1       0
(60, 120]        1       0       1       1
(120, 180]       0       1       1       0
```

---

**Update**: `np.histogram2d` is a good option but a bit more verbose:

```
hist, _, _ = np.histogram2d(x=df['DIR'], y=df['VEL'],
                             bins = (vel_interval, dir_interval))

out = pd.DataFrame(hist.astype(int), 
                   index=[f'{x}-{y}' for x,y in zip(vel_interval[:-1], 
                                                      vel_interval[1:])],
                   columns=[f'{x}-{y}' for x,y in zip(dir_interval[:-1], 
                                                    dir_interval[1:])]
                  )
```

Output:

```
         0-1  1-2  2-3  3-4  4-5
0-60       0    1    2    1    0
60-120     0    1    0    1    1
120-180    0    0    1    1    0
180-240    0    0    0    0    0
240-300    0    0    0    0    0
300-360    0    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: Can I also easily mask a value? For example, if 999 occurs in VEL or DIR, it is not included?

Comment: I checked both your solutions with a large datafile. The histogram method gives the correct solution (checked with commercial software), but the crossstab method is slightly of (probably on the border the count is assigned to a different class)

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
vel_interval = [0,60,120,180,240,300,360]
dir_interval = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
s=(pd.cut(df.DIR, vel_interval,list(np.arange(120,360,60))))\
.astype(str).str.replace('\(|\]','').str.replace('\,\s','-')#Bin Direction
h=(pd.cut(df.VEL, dir_interval,list(np.arange(1,6,1)))).\
astype(str).str.replace('\(|\]','').str.replace('\,\s','-')#Bin velocity

newindex=pd.Series(vel_interval).astype(str).transform(lambda x: x.shift()+'-'+ x).dropna()#New index

pd.crosstab(s,h).rename_axis(index=None, columns=None).reindex(newindex).fillna('0')#Tabulate result




         1-2 2-3 3-4 4-5
0-60      1   2   1   0
60-120    1   0   1   1
120-180   0   1   1   0
180-240   0   0   0   0
240-300   0   0   0   0
300-360   0   0   0   0
```